# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, файлы

Пишу программу на C#, которая работает с файлами. Открыть на чтение (StreamReader) у меня нормально обрабатывает, а вот открыть файл на запись (StreamWriter) компилятор кидает ошибку System.IO такого типа:
Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу как этот файл используется другим процессом

Comment: Добавьте фрагменты кода с чтением и записью в файл. Но телепат в душе мне подсказывает, что после чтения вы не закрываете ридер и не освобождаете поток.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я разобрался. Да, действительно не закрывал поток

Comment: Все таки оформите вопрос с фрагментами кода, чтобы другие могли увидеть в чем была проблема и как ее исправить. Несущественные части можно опустить или заменить комментарием.

Comment: StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter("Dictionary.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < uniqueWords.Count; i++)
            {
                sWriter.Write(uniqueWords[i] + " ");
            }

Comment: и я это делал в цикле while(true), чтобы отображалось на экране консоли пункты меню и пользователь выбирал конкретное действие

Comment: Значит вы где-то открыли уже файл либо для чтения либо для записи. Покажите код, как вы это делаете и тогда будет понятно, где ошибка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

При работе с файлами, надо помнить, что если вы открыли файл монопольно, то пока не закроете поток связанный с этим файлом, попытки привязать к тому же файлу другой поток будут завершаться исключением. Корректно работу с файлом на чтение и запись можно сделать двумя способами:

Без освобождения потока:

```
Stream myStream;

using (myStream = File.Open(@"\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(myStream);
    myWriter.WriteLine("test");
    //перед чтением необходимо вернуть указатель потока в нужное место, у меня - в начало файла.
    myStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
    Console.Write(myReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

При таком подходе важно указать `FileAccess.ReadWrite` при создании потока и не закрывать `StreamWriter` и `StreamReader`, т.к. они при закрытии закрывают и поток. На все время работы файл будет заблокирован для других приложений.

С освобождением потока:

```
Stream myStream;

using (myStream = File.Open(@"\test.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write))
{
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(myStream);
    myWriter.WriteLine("test");
}

using (myStream = File.Open(@"\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
{
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
    Console.Write(myReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

В этом случае после чтения и записи поток освобождается. Соответственно между чтением и записью (в любом порядке) файл доступен другим процессам.

Блоки `using` гарантируют освобождение потока. Вместо этого можно использовать `myStream.Close()`, но про это можно случайно забыть, так что `using` надежнее.

В принципе, отдельно поток можно и не создавать, `StreamWriter` и `StreamReader` сами умеют создавать поток к файлу по его имени, в таком случае код короче:

```
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"\test.txt"))
{
    myWriter.WriteLine("test");
}

using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(@"\test.txt"))
{
    Console.Write(myReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Но вы лишаетесь возможности настроить FileShare, и запретить другим программам блокировать файл пока вы им не пользуетесь.

Кроме всего перечисленного крайне желательно прежде чем открывать потоки чтения-записи, проверять существование файла, наличие необходимых прав доступа и т.д. потому что отсутствие какой либо из проверок в большинстве случаев гарантирует исключение.